# Minimum number of rotations of a binary tree to convert it into another

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

I have the following binary tree, which I'm trying to convert into the target binary tree (second tree in the post) using minimum number of tree rotations. The theoretical minimum number of rotations for this tree is 5, however, the smallest value I can figure out is 6 rotations, I have copied the rotations as well, what am I missing?

**Tree:**

 `1 
  \
   \
   3
  / \
 /   \
 2    5
    /   \
   /     \
   4      7
        /   \
       /     \
       6     11
            / \
           /   \
           9   12
          / \ 
          8 10`

**Target Tree:**

     `1
      \
       \
       11
      /   \
     /     \
     9      12
    /  \
   /    \
   3     10
  /  \
 /    \
 2     5
      / \
     /   \
     4   7
        / \
        6 8`

The rotations I have tried so far (all of which require 6 rotations):

**Order1:**

`Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 9`

**Order2:**

`Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 9`

**Order3:**

`Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 9`

**Order4:**

`Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 9`

**Order5:**

`Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 7 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 5 and pivot 9
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 11
Rotate left with root 3 and pivot 9`

Comment: Could you define the rotation? What does it mean in your case? Also the tree looks flat right now.

Comment: @Evil Rotations are simple binary tree rotations, such as those used by AVL trees for balancing. See the wikipedia post on rotations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation.

Comment: In general, there is a relationship between the rotation distance between binary search trees and the flip distance between triangulations of convex polygons (i.e they are in bijective correspondence), and this problem is not known to be NP-Complete or in P (see the final few slides here: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alubiw/CS763/Lecture11.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rotate 9 right around 11 to make a linear tree.